# Why am I getting the wrong solar alt/az from PyEphem?

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

I've only begun using PyEphem today so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I get such incredibly incorrect results when I try to calculate the solar altitude and azimuth from an observer point.  The code is really simple so I can't imagine where it's going wrong:

```
import ephem
loc = ephem.Observer()
loc.lon = -118.897123
loc.lat = 34.247778
loc.elevation = 55
sun = ephem.Sun()
sun.compute(loc)
```

When I print out `loc` I get:

```
<ephem.Observer date='2020/6/26 21:10:06' epoch='2000/1/1 12:00:00' lon='-6812:18:12.0' lat='1962:15:11.3' elevation=55.0m horizon=0:00:00.0 temp=15.0C pressure=1010.0mBar>
```

The lat/long and time are all right even though they're presented a little weirdly in the `print(loc)` statement.  Still it's 2:10PM in Southern California so there is no reason that `sun.alt` and `sun.az` should print out `1.299` and `6.011` respectively.

Can someone please explain what the issue is here?  PyEphem looks like a great library if I could just figure out how to use it correctly.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `lat` & `lon` as strings and format the `alt` & `az` as strings:

```
>>> loc = ephem.Observer()
>>> loc.lon = '-118.897123'
>>> loc.lat = '34.247778'
>>> sun = ephem.Sun()
>>> sun.compute(loc)
>>> f"{sun.alt} {sun.az}"
'64:36:51.4 251:28:08.8'
>>> loc
<ephem.Observer date='2020/6/26 21:43:46' epoch='2000/1/1 12:00:00' lon='-118:53:49.6' lat='34:14:52.0' elevation=0.0m horizon=0:00:00.0 temp=15.0C pressure=1010.0mBar>
>>>
```

Comment: @MilesZoltak It looks like PyEphem is implemented mostly in `C` as `libastro`.  It must be that `libastro` must have strings passed to it to parse into a scalar form of the  `degrees:minutes:seconds` representation.  The same must be true of the internal representation of `az` and `alt`--that is they need to be coerced into strings to display as `degrees:minutes:seconds`.  Good luck with your stargazing!